# Addback method for a doubly linked list

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list

I realize this should be a very easy method to implement and I have no idea why this code is not working.

I get a `NullPointerException` at `tail.next = node`. If it is not commented out, it does not pass the tester.

```
public void addBack (int x)
{
    IntegerNode node = new IntegerNode(x,null);
    if (head == null)
        head = node;
    else{
        node.prev = tail;
        //tail.next = node;
        tail = node;

    }

    count++;
}
```

Comment: tail is reference to the last object in list

Comment: If you have no elements in the list and try to `addBack`, what is the value of `tail`?

Comment: well i could make tail point towards node aswell but does it really matter?

Comment: Well obviously, otherwise it's `null`.

Comment: okay but that doesnt really solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

When the list is empty, set your head and tail to the new element.  Should be ok after that, though more null checks are rarely a bad idea.

```
if (head == null) {
    head = node;
    tail = node;
} else {
    node.prev = tail;
    tail.next = null; // Did you really mean tail.next = node?  This looks more likely..
    tail = node;
}
```

Comment: should i just get rid of the tail.next completely?Although i think that not having tail.next = node is the source of my problem later in the tester

Comment: If you need a tail, then why would it ever have anything other than next = null?  Is it a circular list?  If it's not circular, then tail.next will always be null.  If it is circular, then why do you need a tail at all?